# what does this xml code in the body of POST request mean?

Tags: xml, http, post

I am trying to implement the POST request for my HTTP server , The [tutorials point website](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_methods.htm) has used the method for applying some kind of change , and the server returns this in the response body:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Request Processed Successfully</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

the POST request that was sent has this entity body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://clearforest.com/">string</string>
```

what does this xml code is supposed to do and what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems they've stolen their content from [Reuters OpenCalais documentation](http://www.opencalais.com/documentation/calais-web-service-api/interpreting-api-response/http-request-and-response-examples/ht) (ClearForest is also a Reuters subsidiary.

Unfortunately there isn't any documentation I could find on the ClearForest XML Schema to describe it further.

Comment: Can you at least tell me what such `xml` requests can do?
can they change the contents of a specific file in a specific way? and is this a common application of `POST` request?

Comment: Well, potentially, depending on what code you write that uses it. XML is just a structured markup language, nothing more, nothing less - thats the beauty of it, it doesn't *do* anything .